# How to replace a image button with a plain image

Tags: php, jquery

```
function insertQuestion(form) {   

var x = "<img src='Images/plussigndisabled.jpg' width='30' height='30' alt='Look Up Previous Question' class='plusimage' name='plusbuttonrow'/><span id='plussignmsg'>(Click Plus Sign to look <br/> up Previous Questions)</span>" ;

    if (qnum == <?php echo (int)$_SESSION['textQuestion']; ?>) {

   $('#mainPlusbutton').html(x); // no need to create a jQuery object

}

//append rows into a table code, not needed for this question

}

<form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($action); ?>" method="post">

<table id="question">

<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<a onclick="return plusbutton();">
<img src="Images/plussign.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="Look Up Previous Question" class="plusimage" id="mainPlusbutton" name="plusbuttonrow"/>
</a>
<span id="plussignmsg">(Click Plus Sign to look up Previous Questions)</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id="questionBtn" align="center">
<tr>
<th>
<input id="addQuestionBtn" name="addQuestion" type="button" value="Add Question" onClick="insertQuestion(this.form)" />
</th>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

What is suppose to happen with code above is that the user clicks on the "Add Question" button and this will append question numbers into a table. Now what is suppose to happen is that if the if statement is met in the jquery function, then it suppose to replace the plus button image `Images/plussign.jpg` with `Images/plussigndisabled.jpg`. But it is not doing this.

So my question is that what is the best way to replace an image button with another image button? Also in the document ready function I need it to go back to displaying the `Images/plussign.jpg` button.

Comment: What do you store in $_SESSION['textQuestion']; ?
Or, little less complicated, can you debug the script and see if it really meets the `if` statement?

Comment: @KiroConeski The if statement is definetly matched. I did not included it in code above but I included some disable attributes when the if statement was reached and it does disable the attrbutes. The session variable simply contains the total number of questions there are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can use `replaceWith()` method if you want to replace the whole button with new html

```
$('#mainPlusbutton').replaceWith(x);
```

API Reference: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

I suspect you really only want to replace the `src` of the button, and simultaneously disable it which can be done with `attr()` and `prop()` methods

```
var newImage='Images/plussigndisabled.jpg';

$('#mainPlusbutton').attr('src',newImage).prop('disabled',true);
```

Please be aware that ID's must be unique in a page, so if you are duplicating rows you will need to revise to using class and modifying a traverse to change the appropriate element

Comment: The only problem I am having is that it is not disabling the click. I I click on the image, it still performs the click method. If you look at the html for the image button, it performs a `onclick="return plusbutton();"` function. How can I disable this?

Comment: remove inline `onclick` completely and use jQuery, then withing jQuery click handler use `prop()` method to check if button disabled or not. Otherwise just replace the html using my first solution

Comment: Will the best thing to do is replace the `<a>` tag by giving it in an id to remove the onclick in the html, or is it better to put an id in the `<td>` tag and replace the whole td. Can you show me how you would replace it so I know best way to replace the html

Comment: Yeah I tried the replaceWith() code and it shows the other image which is great but like I said it doesn't disable the click, if I click on it it still performs the onclick method which I on't want to happen when the image has been replaced to display (x)

Comment: chain the following to either method `.parent().addClass('disabled')` and check for that class within `plusbutton()`. If you are going to use jQuery, you really should stop using any inline `onlcick` and use jQuery to handle click events. Is easier to manage in the long run

Comment: Ok I just need you to provide one last edit as Im not strong with jquery anyway. Can you update you answer to include the code where it enables click events in jquery in the document ready function and then in the if statement provide the code where jquery disables the click event. Then I will mark your answer and upvote it

Comment: Hi, just wanted to know if you are still there, you can tke your time on when you want to edit your answer but just wanted to make sure if you have seen my comments above

Answer (score 1):

That code gave me a brief headache.

Your code

```
$('#mainPlusbutton').html(x);
```

refers to an image tag.  Your invocation of `html` is supposed to replace the *inside* of the tag, but image tags cannot contain anything, so there's nothing to replace.

Comment: Do you know what I should change this to or do you have a better idea in tackling this issue?

Comment: move the id `mainPlusbutton` to the images parent (the anchor/link tag)  That way, you can revert back and forth between the disabled image or not.--- but then you also have a span tag that you also probably want in there.... do you want to replace that too?  ... If you want my "better" idea, I probably wouldn't even mess with swapping contents; I'd just choose what to display by CSS and changing a class property somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use span or div to enclosed this image tag.

```
<img src="Images/plussign.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="Look Up Previous Question" class="plusimage" id="mainPlusbutton" name="plusbuttonrow"/>
```

and change the script with this.

```
$('#mainPlusbutton').parent().html(x);
```